# How to find a position of a step that changes it's properties as function of position

Tags: matlab

I want to find a position of a step in my noisy data. After a few attempts I tried using an edge detector  or to convolve with  a match filter to get the position of the step, The problem that neither is accurate because the step changes its shape as function of position.

For example, given my data vector is 1000 elements long, the step width will be 30 around pixel number 200, and 70 around pixel number 700, similar to the way a wavepacket broaden due to dispersion. There are more properties that change somewhat, so the general question is, how can I find the position of the step? A matched filter is only limited to a specific shape, and will give inaccurate position. An edge detector is sensitive to the slope and also will give an inaccurate position.  What other approaches do you know? I'd be happy to learn new ideas.

Here is an example of steps that change vs positions without noise or other features
[image]

And here are the same steps + noise and one additional feature (displaced for better visualization).
[image]

Comment: Can you be clearer on what you mean by "step"? Is this a part of your data that looks like a [step function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) -seep rise (or fall) and then a flat plateau (or basin)? An image would be helpful.

Comment: I've added a simulated sample that somewhat captures my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I would do a noise-insensitive kind of numerical differentiation, and find its peaks (I don't have Matlab at hand, so this may have typos):

```
n = length(x); % x is the original data vector
m = 30; % smallest step width you expect
y = zeros(n - m, 1); % the "numerical derivative" of x
for i = 1 + m : n
   y(i - m) = x(i) - x(i - m);
end
figure; plot(y)
% now find the peaks of y using a sliding window and thresholding
% sliding window width should be the largest step width you expect
```

This simple approach worked for me in the past.

Another method to calculate numerical derivative is to calculate the slope at the middle of a (parabolic) [Savitzky-Golay filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitzky%E2%80%93Golay_filter_for_smoothing_and_differentiation). You should apply the filter in a sliding window. Again, its width should be the smallest step width you expect. The advantages of the SG filter are that (1) calculating the slope of the fitted parabola is easy, and (2) there will be no time offset in the derivative. Calculating slope after applying a usual linear smoothing filter won't work because these filters shift the smoothed signal in time, so the timing of the step will also be shifted.

Comment: +1 for Savitzky-Golay. If you need a more general solution for functions that might vary a bunch in shape and noise, I'd try that first. Matlab's [`sgolay`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/sgolay.html).